# First Order Non-linear Differential Equation Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for a (hopefully closed form) solution to the non-linear DE of the form

$$\frac{dv}{dt} = A v^2 + B.$$

Other than being real there are no constraints on $A$ and $B$. I would assume that this is a well-explored equation as it is the equation of motion ($v$ = velocity) of an object experiencing aerodynamic drag, frictional drag, and a constant propelling force.

Be kind - I have not tried to work in this world since the early 1970's :-)

Thanks.

dave

Comment: One of things we didn't have in the 1970s is [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+v%27%28t%29+%3D+A*v%28t%29%5E2+%2B+B): it solves this equation right away.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $AB \neq 0$.

Changing the variables according to $$t=\frac 1{\sqrt {|AB|}}\,s$$and $$v=\sqrt {\left|\frac BA \right|}\,w$$ one has to solve $$\frac {dw}{ds}=\pm1\pm w^2$$ so $$s=\pm \int \frac 1{1+w^2}\,dw=\pm \arctan w +c$$ or $$s=\pm \int \frac 1{1-w^2}\,dw=\pm \text {arctanh}\, w +c$$ i.e., renaming the constant $$w=\pm\tan\,(s+c)$$ or $$w=\pm\tanh\, (s+c)$$ Finally, if $AB>0$ $$v=\frac {\sqrt {AB}}A \tan\,(\sqrt {AB}\,t+c)$$ otherwise $$v=-\frac {\sqrt {-AB}}A \tanh\,(\sqrt {-AB}\,t+c)$$ Maple confirms, using the *assume* command.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: rewrite $$\frac{dv}{Av^2+B}=dt$$ integrating gives $$v(t)=\frac{\sqrt{B} \tan \left(\sqrt{A} \sqrt{B} c_1+\sqrt{A} \sqrt{B}
   t\right)}{\sqrt{A}}$$

Comment: Is $\sqrt A \sqrt B c_1$ a constant ?

Comment: this must know the OP, but i would say yes

Comment: I think that this is a good way of doing it if $A$ and $B$ have the same sign. If that is not true, it might be better to use logarithms while integrating and expressing the end result using exponential functions. Of course that is doable from the result as well...

Comment: Three comments - I am new here and am SO IMPRESSED by the quick and quality responses. Yes, it is separable and relatively straight-forward to solve. I am very old and rusty, it would seem :-) Thank you. dave

Comment: @DaveLee. You are very welcome and welcome to Math SE ! This is a marvelous site for mathematics at any level. When you have a problem, try to show what you tried. If you are totally stuck because you lost your experience, just tell it as you did. Cheers :-)

Comment: @DaveLee acceleration increases with speed?( sign?)

Comment: Narasimham, I'm not sure that I understand your comment/question. But for an object experiencing aerodynamic drag, frictional drag, and a constant propelling force, A is negative and the sign of B depends on the size of the propelling force vs. the frictional force.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that the equation is separable, as 
@Dr.SonnhardGraubner answered, the key idea is to arrive to something close to a well known formula (this is something I suggest you to always do if you lost contact with this area for too long - there are very good tables for many integrals).

The closest I can see is $$\frac {1}{1+z^2}=\Big(\tan^{-1}(z)\Big)'$$ So, assuming for simplicity that $A>0$, $B>0$, which ensures the square roots cause no problem, try changing variable $$v=\sqrt{\frac BA}z\qquad dv=\sqrt{\frac BA}dz$$ After some minor simplifications, one gets $$\frac{dv}{Av^2+B}=dt=\frac 1{\sqrt{AB}}\frac {dz}{1+z^2}$$ that is to say $$\frac {dz}{1+z^2}=\sqrt{AB}dt$$ Now integrate both sides $$\tan ^{-1}(z)=\sqrt{AB}t+C$$ So,$$z=\tan(\sqrt{AB}t+C)$$ Now, going back from $z$ to $v$, $$v=\sqrt{\frac BA}\tan(\sqrt{AB}t+C)$$ the integration constant $C$ being probably fixed by some condition.

Comment: @Did. This was what I was just about to write ! Thanks. I do not change the post in order your comment be not diluted. Cheers :-(

Comment: @Did. Thanks for the edit !